# Are these functions logically equivalent?

Tags: c#, linq

I thing the answer is YES? Result at then end will be the same.

```
public bool CustomValidationDuplicateName(string sysPriority)
{
    var systemPriories = (this.gridView.Items.SourceCollection as IEnumerable<SystemPriority>).Where(item => item.ID > 0).ToList();
    var selectedItem = this.gridView.SelectedItem as SystemPriority;
    foreach (SystemPriority item in systemPriories)
    {
        if (item.Title == sysPriority && item != selectedItem) 
            return false;
    }           
    return true;
}

public bool CustomValidationDuplicateName2(string sysPriority)
{
    var systemPriories = (this.gridView.Items.SourceCollection as IEnumerable<SystemPriority>).Where(item => item.ID > 0).ToList();
    var selectedItem = this.gridView.SelectedItem as SystemPriority;
    return systemPriories.All(item => item.Title != sysPriority || item == selectedItem);
}


public bool CustomValidationDuplicateName(string sysPriority)
{
    var systemPriories = (this.gridView.Items.SourceCollection as IEnumerable<SystemPriority>).Where(item => item.ID > 0).ToList();
    var selectedItem = this.gridView.SelectedItem as SystemPriority;
    return systemPriories.All(item => item.Title == sysPriority && item != selectedItem);
}
```

I thing the answer is YES? Result at then end will be the same.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Pet-peeve warning... please correct the spelling of your method names!  It should be **Duplicate** not Dublicate.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `!systemPriorities.All(...)` for one of the two custom validation functions?

Comment: Done!!! I did it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

However, you should get rid of the `ToList()`, and combine the `Where()` and `All()` filters:

```
public bool CustomValidationDublicateName2(string sysPriority)
{
    return (this.gridView.Items.SourceCollection as IEnumerable<SystemPriority>)
         .All(item => item.ID < 0 
                   || item.Title != sysPriority 
                   || item == (SystemPriority)this.gridView.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: That wasn't what I meant.

Comment: Sorry... yeah, that's better. Forgot for a moment that .All() could include the full predicate :(

Answer (score 4):

Yes, those functions are equal.

Look up the [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to see why `!(A && B) == !A || !B`. Then you'll see that the conditionals do the same thing.

```
!(item.Title == sysPriority && item != selectedItem)
    ==
(item.Title != sysPriority || item == selectedItem)
```